# Content Uri to file URI cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap

[This is my Content URI ,I want to convert it to file URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE0oH.png)

I am trying to import a attachment from gmail,so i am getting the uri from webintent but that is the content uri,iwanted to convert to file uri

I tried many approaches in various questions but still my code is not able to call  get success.I am not understanding whats wrong with my code

```
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
if(url.startsWith('content://')) {
    // url is the url the intent was launched with
    alert(url);
    window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, function(local)
    {   deferred.resolve('file://'+result)
    },function (error)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
    );


});
```

Its is going into error state

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to download a web file and have it locally? If you could provide more information and context here, that might be helpful.

Comment: @ftrotter i added the info and yeah i am trying to download the file from the gmail and attach

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve is click on the file from gmail and get it in your app, maybe have a look at this plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-intent